# Get all Elements where the first element grouped by 'X' property has 'Y' value not null

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hi so to put a bit of context I have a list of Orders, these orders have a property named referral link, as well as a userID linked to this order, and I am being asked to query all Orders in a certain date range that either has a referral link or the first order made by the user has a referral link.
Currently, this was my attempt but this is giving me an exception when I debug telling me this is not translatable to SQL.

```cs
public async Task<List<Order>> GetOrdersForRevenueReportFromMarketingTeam(RevenueReportDatesRequest dates)
        {
            var orders = Table.AsQueryable();
            var query =
                from o in orders
                .Include(o => o.ReferralLink)
                from first in orders
                    .Where(first => first.UserId == o.UserId)
                    .OrderBy(first => first.CreatedDate)
                    .Take(1)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                where
                    o.ReferralLink != null||
                    first.Status.Contains("refunded") == false &&
                    first.Fulfilled == true &&
                    first.ReferralLink != null &&
                    o.CreatedDate >= dates.StartDate &&
                    o.CreatedDate <= dates.EndDate &&
                    o.Fulfilled == true &&
                    o.Status.Contains("refunded") == false
                select o;
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

I would appreciate any help!

UPDATE**
I have updated the code to what I have now since I think it would help, English is also not my first language, I apologize if I make it a bit hard to understand.

The idea is to check with an OR condition, kind of what I am doing right now, this, returns the Orders I want, this is partially working, however, I think I might need a JOIN statement somehow, cause the issue I am having is the next, I need the orders that did not possess a referral link, BUT its first user's order did, to have that first order referral link, cause at the moment of the query those order, have a ref link null, since the query is only checking if the first had a referral link.

To further explain what I am looking for, the workaround although I do not like it because I am looping a query to DB, would be to do the next with the list of orders I receive

```
foreach (var order in orderList)
                {
                    if (order.ReferralLink == null)
                    {
                        var firstOrder = await _orderRepository.GetFirstOrderFromUser(order.UserId).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        order.ReferralLink = firstOrder.ReferralLink;
                    }
                }
```

which would query for the first order from that user's order within the date range and then equal the referral link to that first order referral link.

So, is there a way to add with a join or something like that, that ref link from the first order, to the orders that had null as referral link but the first order from that user didn't?

Comment: Which EF version?

Comment: And why you return `List<List<Order>>`? Why not just `List<Order>`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv 4.6.2
As for the return is because this return a list of list, list of list of orders grouped by user ID.

Comment: Well added answer, I can group by user, but I do not see any reason to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query.

Changed returned type to `Task<List<Order>>`

```cs
public Task<List<Order>> GetOrdersForRevenueReportFromMarketingTeam(RevenueReportDatesRequest dates)
{
    var orders = Table.AsQueryable();

    var query = 
        from o in orders
        from first in orders
            .Where(first => first.UserId == o.UserId && first.ReferralLink != null)
            .OrderBy(first => 
                  first.CreatedDate >= dates.StartDate 
               && first.CreatedDate <= dates.EndDate ? 0 : 1)
            .ThenBy(first => first.CreatedDate)
            .Take(1)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
        where first.ReferralLink != null &&
            o.CreatedDate >= dates.StartDate &&
            o.CreatedDate <= dates.EndDate &&
            o.Fulfilled == true &&
            o.Status.Contains("refunded") == false
        select o;

    return query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed the issue, I guess I was grouping them cause I thought it would be easier to filter that way, but your approach makes more sense, again thanks a lot :)

Comment: @DanMartz, updated answer to fix `async` issue also.

Comment: Hi @Svyatoslav Danyliv to further this question, do you know if there is a way in the query to add the ReferralLink from the first order to the order from the date range which first-order had X ReferralLink ?

Comment: @DanMartz, updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! althought I am not sure if I explained myself well enough, what I meant was in the end where you are returning the o, I need that for the orders that do not possess a referral link within the date range, the first.referralLink is joined with that record, is that possible?

Comment: Updated, I hope that I've understand it correctly. English is not my native language.

Comment: I updated the answer and explained it a bit better and updated the current code, I really appreciate your help and I am very grateful for your answer, this query has been driving me crazy for a few weeks and you are the only person who has given me a good answer, thanks you very much :)